# Is glue needed to hang a cabinet with a french cleat?

Tags: cabinets, adhesive

I have an overjohn that comes with a french cleat. Someone told me that all I needed to do was  secure the french cleat to the wall and just hang the overjohn on it, no glue or anything else.

Is this true, can the cabinet just be hung on a piece of wood that's attached to the wall without any glue or screws attaching the cabinet to the cleat?

Answer (score 3):

No glue needed. the angle of the cleat and gravity does to trick. It will not need it but you can run a screw into the framing to solve any issue you may have.

Comment: +1 Screws are routinely run into framing near the bottom of the cabinet to reduce the likelihood of vibrational movement on the cleat (although the weight of the cabinet and contents is generally enough).